# Python: Input variable for my "matching" function

Tags: python, function, input

I have a lot of lists such as:

```
ABCC8 = ['TRIM29', 'IGL@', 'DOCK6', 'SVEP1', 'S100A11', 'EPHA2', 'KLHL7', 'ANXA3', 'NAB1', 'CELF2', 'EDNRB', 'PLAGL1', 'IL6ST', 'S100A8', 'CKLF', 'TIPARP', 'CDH3', 'MAP3K8', 'LYST', 'LEPR', 'FHL2', 'ARL4C', 'IL1RN', 'ESR1', 'CD93', 'ATP2B4', 'KAT2B', 'ELOVL5', 'SCD', 'SPTBN1', 'AKAP13', 'LDLR', 'ADRB2', 'LTBP4', 'TGM2', 'TIMP3', 'RAN', 'LAMA3', 'ASPH', 'ID4', 'STX11', 'CNN2', 'EGR1']

APP = ['GULP1', 'PREPL', 'FHL1', 'METTL7A', 'TRIM13', 'YPEL5', 'PTEN', 'FAM190B', 'GSN', 'UBL3', 'PTGER3', 'COBLL1', 'EPB41L3', 'KLF4', 'BCL2L2', 'CYLD', 'SLK', 'ENSA', 'SKAP2', 'FBXO3', 'PDCD4', 'ATP2A2', 'AKAP11', 'PAFAH1B1', 'RALGAPA1', 'YWHAZ', 'BNIP3L', 'ATP8A1', 'TNXB', 'DICER1', 'C17orf91', 'BEX4', 'PPM1A', '2017-09-10', 'NDRG2', 'NCOA1', 'NAB1', 'STX7', 'ZFAND5', 'CD47', 'SFRS5', 'CLASP2', 'PBX1', 'NR3C1', 'ABCA8', 'ETFDH', 'RBPMS', 'FOXO1', 'KLF6', 'ADH1B', 'RAB22A', 'CCNG2', 'NFIB', 'IDS', 'NR3C2', 'MAF', 'NDEL1', 'EZR', 'PCDH9', 'KIAA0494', 'CITED2', 'MGEA5', 'RUFY3', 'ALDH3A2', 'N4BP2L2', 'EPS15', 'TSPAN5', 'SNRPN', 'SSBP2', 'ELOVL5', 'C5orf4', 'FOXN3', 'ABCA5', 'SEC62', 'PELI1', 'MYCBP2', 'USP15', 'TACC1', 'SHMT1', 'RNF103', 'CDC14B', 'SYNE1', 'NDN', 'PHKB', 'EIF1', 'TROVE2', 'MBD4', 'GAB1']

BECN1 = ['LMNA', 'NHP2L1', 'IDS', 'ATP6V0B', 'ENSA', 'TBCB', 'NDUFA13', 'TOLLIP', 'PLEKHB2', 'MBOAT7', 'C16orf13', 'PGAM1', 'MIF', 'ACTR1A', 'OAZ1', 'GNAS', 'ARF1', 'MAPKAPK3', 'LCMT1', 'ATP6V1D', 'FLOT1', 'PRR13', 'COX5B', 'PGP', 'CYB561', 'CNIH4', 'COX6B1', 'ARPC5L', 'NCKIPSD', 'C9orf16', 'LSM4', 'ATP5L', 'C14orf2', 'AURKAIP1', 'MRPL41', 'PDPK1', 'NOP10', 'CANT1', 'CALM3', 'PSEN2', 'C9orf86', 'ATP6V0E1', 'PIN1', 'LARP1', 'HTATIP2', 'PPP1R7', 'HCFC1R1', 'UQCR10', 'FAM134A', 'GPAA1', 'THY1', 'PPM1A', 'NAPA', 'NDUFC2', 'EPS8L1', 'PSME2', 'UBE2M', 'ORMDL2', 'TCEB2', 'RMND5B', 'ATPIF1', 'RNF19B', 'PEBP1', 'PCBP2', 'GHITM', 'AP3S2', 'TSPAN5', 'AP2S1', 'C20orf24', 'RABIF', 'NDUFB2', 'PFDN2', 'GPR172A', 'RTN4', 'GAPDH', 'MAPK13', 'FKBP8', 'PTGER3', 'BSCL2', 'TUBG1', 'FAM162A', 'GDI1', 'SPTLC2', 'YWHAZ', 'BCAP31', 'OSBPL1A', 'ATP6AP1', 'CALM1', 'PEX16', 'MYCBP2']

ARNTL = ['NCAM1', 'SLC11A2', 'RPL35A', 'PDLIM5', 'RPL31', 'NFIB', 'GYG2', 'IGHG1', 'NAAA', 'DLC1', 'EPOR', 'DIO2', 'ESR1', 'KLK10', 'CYP2C9', 'SPN', 'RPS9', 'PRELP', 'CYP3A43', 'PLAGL1', 'COBLL1', 'ADCK2', 'RPL13', 'NRP2', 'SCEL', 'DOCK6', 'NENF', 'MLLT4', 'SERPINB13', 'PALMD', 'TMEM132A', 'ASAP3', 'MTAP', 'NOVA1', 'ALOX12', 'SPINK5', 'LDB3', 'ATP5S', 'LMNA', 'BAIAP2', 'FZD4', 'GNAS', 'OBSL1', 'TCL6', 'ICOSLG', 'MACROD2', 'MAST4', 'EDA', 'ADAM22', 'CSHL1', 'SYNGR1', 'THBS1', 'PEX16', 'NOS1', 'SLCO1A2', 'CYP2A7', 'PRDM2', 'DTNA', 'HSD17B4', 'RPL29', 'PDCD4', 'IL1RN', 'CASZ1', 'C9orf16', 'RGS12', 'TRD@', 'ATP1A2', 'MPRIP', 'PDE4C', 'SPTLC2', 'TNXB', 'DDAH2', 'AOX1', 'PAIP2B', 'HNF4A', 'GLS', 'EMP1', 'ARHGEF4', 'FUT6', 'ACACB', 'NR5A2', 'N4BP2L1', 'APAF1', 'DSC2', 'EDNRB', 'RPL27A', 'CYP2C18']

I have a function which returns me the number of matches of same strings among the different lists of strings compared to my reference (`ref`) list.

    def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
        reference = set(ref)
        lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
        for matches, name, a_list in lists:
            print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))

    sort_by_matches(APP, [("ABCC8", ABCC8), ("APP", APP), ("BECN1", BECN1), ("ARNTL", ARNTL), ("BMI1", BMI1), ("CASP8", CASP8), ("CASP9", CASP9), ("CLOCK", CLOCK), ("CRAT", CRAT), ("CRY2", CRY2), ("CSF1", CSF1), ("CTCF", CTCF), ("DNMT1", DNMT1), ("EP300", EP300), ("FBXW7", FBXW7), ("FOXA1", FOXA1), ("FOXO1", FOXO1), ("FOXO3", FOXO3), ("GADD34", GADD34), ("GATA3", GATA3), ("GCK", GCK), ("GLI1", GLI1), ("GLP1", GLP1), ("GLP1R", GLP1R), ("GLUT1", GLUT1),("GLUT2", GLUT2),("HES1", HES1),("HEY1", HEY1),("HIF1A", HIF1A),("HNF1A", HNF1A),("HNF4A", HNF4A),("ICMT", ICMT),("ID1", ID1),("IDH1", IDH1),("IL4", IL4),("IL6", IL6),("LC3A", LC3A),("LYL1", LYL1),("MFSD2A", MFSD2A),("MOAP1", MOAP1),("MTNR1B", MTNR1B),("MTOR", MTOR),("MYF5", MYF5),("MYOD1", MYOD1),("MSTN", MSTN),("NANOG", NANOG),("NOTCH1", NOTCH1),("NR1D1", NR1D1),("POU5F1", POU5F1),("PAX7", PAX7),("PDK1", PDK1),("PER2", PER2),("PHF6", PHF6),("PRMT5", PRMT5),("PSEN1", PSEN1),("PSEN2", PSEN2),("PTCH1", PTCH1),("RMST", RMST),("RUNX1", RUNX1),("SETD2", SETD2),("SIN3A", SIN3A),("SOCS1", SOCS1),("SOX2", SOX2),("STAT3", STAT3),("STK11", STK11),("TAF1", TAF1),("TCF3", TCF3),("TEAD1", TEAD1), ("TERT", TERT),("RANKL", RANKL),("TOP2A", TOP2A), ("TOX3", TOX3), ("TRIM28", TRIM28), ("TSHZ2", TSHZ2), ("TSHZ3", TSHZ3), ("TSP1", TSP1), ("TWIST1", TWIST1), ("FN1", FN1), ("VHL", VHL), ("WLS", WLS), ("WNT3", WNT3), ("WNT3A", WNT3A), ("WNT5A", WNT5A), ("WT1", WT1), ("YAP1", YAP1), ('MYBPC3', MYBPC3),  ("PPARG", PPARG), ("NKD1", NKD1), ("LRP5", LRP5), ("SMO", SMO), ("CSNK1E", CSNK1E), ("DKK1", DKK1), ("MYH7", MYH7), ("AXIN2", AXIN2), ("TCF7", TCF7), ("NEUROD1", NEUROD1), ("FZD5", FZD5), ("FZD8", FZD8), ("CREB1", CREB1), ("TCF7L2", TCF7L2), ("SOX17", SOX17), ("TP53", TP53), ("PTGER3", PTGER3), ("FERMT2", FERMT2), ("WNT1", WNT1), ("WNT7B", WNT7B), ("MDM4", MDM4), ("IL10", IL10 ),  ("DVL1", DVL1 ), ("PGR", PGR), ("TSC1", TSC1), ("ASCL2", ASCL2)])
```

How can I use 'input' variable for the `ref` in my function `sort_by_matches(ref, lists)` instead of copy-pasting different my function every time with different reference.

Copy pasting the above matching function is too long, since I have hundreds of lists. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See "reflection". Note that if you do choose this path, it's a good idea (for security purposes) to only allow only method names from a list of allowable names.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'different input variable'?

Comment: @pvg different input variable is using different reference list with each iteration, such as ABCC8, APP, BECN1, ARNTL, and so on, as my reference list.

Comment: Pass in a collection of reference lists instead of just one? I feel like I'm not understanding something about the question since it looks like you know python well enough to come up with the parametrization you want.

Comment: It sounds like a job for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: I think I'm interpreting it the same as @pvg. Do you have a bunch of lists and want to compare the intersections of each pair of them? If so you could redefine your function sort_by_matches to accept a single ordered collection containing all your lists, then loop through and compare each list to all lists following it in the collection.

Comment: @pvg dear pvg, thanks for comment, since I have too many lists, I don't wanna copy paste the function with different reference list, in the example above, `APP`

How can I achieve this? I am beginner in python, function was prepared with professional assistance.

Comment: @Poosh how can I redefine my function? So that collection can include hundreds of lists, and accordingly function is not too long as the current function.

Comment: Need more information. Where are your "hundreds of lists" coming from? Which of these lists need to be a reference, and which lists need to be compared to the reference? When you mention "Copy pasting the above matching function", are you referring the function call or the actual function? The function only needs to be defined once within the scope.

Comment: @Poosh essentially, the number of my lists (such as APP, ABCC8) is constantly increasing.
I have this function with produces desired results. But since the number of lists increases constantly, I don't know a short way to call this function. How can I do it?

Comment: @Nguyen, are the lists all defined like they are in your code above, or are you dynamically accessing the lists? If they are accessed dynamically, could you add that code to show how they can be accessed? Also, are you wanting to compare every single list to each other, or are there specific lists you want to use as the reference lists and specific lists to compare to the reference lists? Or do the lists that need to be compared to the reference list vary by reference list?

Comment: @Poosh yes indeed I am constantly adding more lists.
how can make a collected and access this lists inside my function?

Comment: @Nguyen, I put an edit in my answer. It will not require you to make any changes to your function, and you can add more lists definitions (as long as you also add an entry for each list into `MY_LISTS`) without changes to your function or the loop that calls the function to perform the list comparisons.

Comment: Dear @Poosh, I don't think you understood what I wanted to do.

I want to simplify the function is such a way that:
    `sort_by_matches(APP, [#collection of my hundreds of lists])` produces the same results as 
    `sort_by_matches(APP, [("ABCC8", ABCC8), ("APP", APP), ("BECN1", BECN1), ("ARNTL", ARNTL)]`

Comment: @Nguyen, your question is talking about passing in different lists to the `ref` parameter of your function. According to your previous comment, you are talking about the `lists` parameter of your function now. You might want to update your question to very specifically indicate what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Poosh please check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344992/python-how-to-call-a-long-function-containing-hundreds-of-lists-in-a-short-form/45345471#45345471

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more succinct way of doing this, as I am new to Python, but I made the following modifications:

The lists you have defined are put into a list of tuples, with the first item in the tuple representing the name of the list, and the second item referencing the list you have already defined (similar to how you're calling your function already):

```
myLists = [("ABCC8", ABCC8), ("APP", APP), ("BECN1", BECN1), ("ARNTL", ARNTL)]
```

I modified the `ref` parameter so your function `sort_by_matches` expects a tuple for that parameter (this is so you can reference the name of the list, if needed):

```
def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(ref[1])
    lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
    for matches, name, a_list in lists:
        print("{} Matches {} in {}".format(ref[0],matches, name))
```

Next, loop over `myLists`, calling `sort_by_matches` for the reference list and all lists following it:

```
i = 0
while(i < len(myLists) - 1):
    sort_by_matches(myLists[i], myLists[i + 1:])
    i = i + 1
```

This compares each list to every other list.

The output looks like this:

> ABCC8 Matches 5 in ARNTL 
>   ABCC8 Matches 2 in APP 
>   ABCC8 Matches 0 in BECN1 
>   APP Matches 7 in BECN1 
>   APP Matches 4 in ARNTL 
>   BECN1 Matches 5 in ARNTL

**EDIT**

You will need a way to reference all the lists some way since they are contained within the code. Below I am storing references to your lists in the variable `MY_LISTS`. You would just need to add an entry to this variable each time you define another list in your program. (However you decide to implement this, since the lists are defined explicitly in the code, there will need to be a collection referencing the lists to avoid having to reference all the lists explicitly each time you call your function.)

No modifications have been made to the `sort_by_matches` function. Instead, in the `while` loop, the name of the current reference list is printed out so you'll know which list the other lists are being compared to.

The loop starts with the first list in `MY_LISTS`, comparing it to all subsequent lists in `MY_LISTS`. In each iteration of the loop, the reference list is only compared to the subsequent lists in `MY_LISTS`. This makes it so a comparison is only performed on every possible pair of lists once.

```
ABCC8 = ['TRIM29', 'IGL@', 'DOCK6', 'SVEP1', 'S100A11', 'EPHA2', 'KLHL7', 'ANXA3', 'NAB1', 'CELF2', 'EDNRB', 'PLAGL1', 'IL6ST', 'S100A8', 'CKLF', 'TIPARP', 'CDH3', 'MAP3K8', 'LYST', 'LEPR', 'FHL2', 'ARL4C', 'IL1RN', 'ESR1', 'CD93', 'ATP2B4', 'KAT2B', 'ELOVL5', 'SCD', 'SPTBN1', 'AKAP13', 'LDLR', 'ADRB2', 'LTBP4', 'TGM2', 'TIMP3', 'RAN', 'LAMA3', 'ASPH', 'ID4', 'STX11', 'CNN2', 'EGR1']

APP = ['GULP1', 'PREPL', 'FHL1', 'METTL7A', 'TRIM13', 'YPEL5', 'PTEN', 'FAM190B', 'GSN', 'UBL3', 'PTGER3', 'COBLL1', 'EPB41L3', 'KLF4', 'BCL2L2', 'CYLD', 'SLK', 'ENSA', 'SKAP2', 'FBXO3', 'PDCD4', 'ATP2A2', 'AKAP11', 'PAFAH1B1', 'RALGAPA1', 'YWHAZ', 'BNIP3L', 'ATP8A1', 'TNXB', 'DICER1', 'C17orf91', 'BEX4', 'PPM1A', '2017-09-10', 'NDRG2', 'NCOA1', 'NAB1', 'STX7', 'ZFAND5', 'CD47', 'SFRS5', 'CLASP2', 'PBX1', 'NR3C1', 'ABCA8', 'ETFDH', 'RBPMS', 'FOXO1', 'KLF6', 'ADH1B', 'RAB22A', 'CCNG2', 'NFIB', 'IDS', 'NR3C2', 'MAF', 'NDEL1', 'EZR', 'PCDH9', 'KIAA0494', 'CITED2', 'MGEA5', 'RUFY3', 'ALDH3A2', 'N4BP2L2', 'EPS15', 'TSPAN5', 'SNRPN', 'SSBP2', 'ELOVL5', 'C5orf4', 'FOXN3', 'ABCA5', 'SEC62', 'PELI1', 'MYCBP2', 'USP15', 'TACC1', 'SHMT1', 'RNF103', 'CDC14B', 'SYNE1', 'NDN', 'PHKB', 'EIF1', 'TROVE2', 'MBD4', 'GAB1']

BECN1 = ['LMNA', 'NHP2L1', 'IDS', 'ATP6V0B', 'ENSA', 'TBCB', 'NDUFA13', 'TOLLIP', 'PLEKHB2', 'MBOAT7', 'C16orf13', 'PGAM1', 'MIF', 'ACTR1A', 'OAZ1', 'GNAS', 'ARF1', 'MAPKAPK3', 'LCMT1', 'ATP6V1D', 'FLOT1', 'PRR13', 'COX5B', 'PGP', 'CYB561', 'CNIH4', 'COX6B1', 'ARPC5L', 'NCKIPSD', 'C9orf16', 'LSM4', 'ATP5L', 'C14orf2', 'AURKAIP1', 'MRPL41', 'PDPK1', 'NOP10', 'CANT1', 'CALM3', 'PSEN2', 'C9orf86', 'ATP6V0E1', 'PIN1', 'LARP1', 'HTATIP2', 'PPP1R7', 'HCFC1R1', 'UQCR10', 'FAM134A', 'GPAA1', 'THY1', 'PPM1A', 'NAPA', 'NDUFC2', 'EPS8L1', 'PSME2', 'UBE2M', 'ORMDL2', 'TCEB2', 'RMND5B', 'ATPIF1', 'RNF19B', 'PEBP1', 'PCBP2', 'GHITM', 'AP3S2', 'TSPAN5', 'AP2S1', 'C20orf24', 'RABIF', 'NDUFB2', 'PFDN2', 'GPR172A', 'RTN4', 'GAPDH', 'MAPK13', 'FKBP8', 'PTGER3', 'BSCL2', 'TUBG1', 'FAM162A', 'GDI1', 'SPTLC2', 'YWHAZ', 'BCAP31', 'OSBPL1A', 'ATP6AP1', 'CALM1', 'PEX16', 'MYCBP2']

ARNTL = ['NCAM1', 'SLC11A2', 'RPL35A', 'PDLIM5', 'RPL31', 'NFIB', 'GYG2', 'IGHG1', 'NAAA', 'DLC1', 'EPOR', 'DIO2', 'ESR1', 'KLK10', 'CYP2C9', 'SPN', 'RPS9', 'PRELP', 'CYP3A43', 'PLAGL1', 'COBLL1', 'ADCK2', 'RPL13', 'NRP2', 'SCEL', 'DOCK6', 'NENF', 'MLLT4', 'SERPINB13', 'PALMD', 'TMEM132A', 'ASAP3', 'MTAP', 'NOVA1', 'ALOX12', 'SPINK5', 'LDB3', 'ATP5S', 'LMNA', 'BAIAP2', 'FZD4', 'GNAS', 'OBSL1', 'TCL6', 'ICOSLG', 'MACROD2', 'MAST4', 'EDA', 'ADAM22', 'CSHL1', 'SYNGR1', 'THBS1', 'PEX16', 'NOS1', 'SLCO1A2', 'CYP2A7', 'PRDM2', 'DTNA', 'HSD17B4', 'RPL29', 'PDCD4', 'IL1RN', 'CASZ1', 'C9orf16', 'RGS12', 'TRD@', 'ATP1A2', 'MPRIP', 'PDE4C', 'SPTLC2', 'TNXB', 'DDAH2', 'AOX1', 'PAIP2B', 'HNF4A', 'GLS', 'EMP1', 'ARHGEF4', 'FUT6', 'ACACB', 'NR5A2', 'N4BP2L1', 'APAF1', 'DSC2', 'EDNRB', 'RPL27A', 'CYP2C18']

MY_LISTS = [("ABCC8", ABCC8), ("APP", APP), ("BECN1", BECN1), ("ARNTL", ARNTL)]

def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
    for matches, name, a_list in lists:
        print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))

i = 0
while(i < len(MY_LISTS) - 1):
    print("Comparing Lists to " + MY_LISTS[i][0])
    sort_by_matches(MY_LISTS[i][1], MY_LISTS[i + 1:])
    i = i + 1
```

The output looks like this:

> Comparing Lists to ABCC8 
>   Matches 5 in ARNTL 
>   Matches 2 in APP 
>   Matches 0 in BECN1 
>   Comparing Lists to APP 
>   Matches 7 in BECN1 
>   Matches 4 in ARNTL 
>   Comparing Lists to BECN1 
>   Matches 5 in ARNTL

Comment: thanks a lot. but I am happy with my function results
just want to build on that function, but with succinct lists collection, instead of pasting giant function every time with changing reference list.

Comment: You only have to define your function once; after that, you can call it whenever you want with different lists.

Comment: thanks but it does not answer my problem.

Comment: Dear @Poosh, I don't like your current code
To say again, I am looking for quick call of my function with anyone from the hundreds of lists as my `ref` list.
The output should be like this:
 `Matches 4 in GLP`
 `Matches 4 in NAN`
 `Matches 4 in NR`
 `Matches 3 in PCS`
 `Matches 3 in FZD`
 `Matches 3 in MYT`
 `Matches 3 in TB`
 `Matches 3 in ORM`
 `Matches 3 in VGL`
 `Matches 3 in LYP`
 `Matches 3 in GAT`