# Python: How to call a long function containing hundreds of lists in a short form

Tags: python, list, function

I have hundreds of lists such as :

```
ABCC8 = ['TRIM29', 'IGL@', 'DOCK6', 'SVEP1', 'S100A11', 'EPHA2', 'KLHL7', 'ANXA3', 'NAB1', 'CELF2', 'EDNRB', 'PLAGL1', 'IL6ST', 'S100A8', 'CKLF', 'TIPARP', 'CDH3', 'MAP3K8', 'LYST', 'LEPR', 'FHL2', 'ARL4C', 'IL1RN', 'ESR1', 'CD93', 'ATP2B4', 'KAT2B', 'ELOVL5', 'SCD', 'SPTBN1', 'AKAP13', 'LDLR', 'ADRB2', 'LTBP4', 'TGM2', 'TIMP3', 'RAN', 'LAMA3', 'ASPH', 'ID4', 'STX11', 'CNN2', 'EGR1']

APP = ['GULP1', 'PREPL', 'FHL1', 'METTL7A', 'TRIM13', 'YPEL5', 'PTEN', 'FAM190B', 'GSN', 'UBL3', 'PTGER3', 'COBLL1', 'EPB41L3', 'KLF4', 'BCL2L2', 'CYLD', 'SLK', 'ENSA', 'SKAP2', 'NR3C2', 'MAF', 'NDEL1', 'EZR', 'PCDH9', 'KIAA0494', 'CITED2', 'MGEA5', 'RUFY3', 'ALDH3A2', 'N4BP2L2', 'EPS15', 'TSPAN5', 'SNRPN', 'SSBP2', 'ELOVL5', 'C5orf4', 'FOXN3', 'ABCA5', 'SEC62', 'PELI1', 'MYCBP2', 'USP15', 'TACC1', 'SHMT1', 'RNF103', 'CDC14B', 'SYNE1', 'NDN', 'PHKB', 'EIF1', 'TROVE2', 'MBD4', 'GAB1']

BECN1 = ['LMNA', 'NHP2L1', 'IDS', 'ATP6V0B', 'ENSA', 'TBCB', 'NDUFA13', 'TOLLIP', 'PLEKHB2', 'MBOAT7', 'C16orf13', 'PGAM1', 'MIF', 'ACTR1A', 'OAZ1', 'GNAS', 'ARF1', 'MAPKAPK3', 'LCMT1', 'ATP6V1D', 'FLOT1', 'PRR13', 'COX5B', 'PGP', 'CYB561', 'CNIH4', 'COX6B1', 'NDUFB2', 'PFDN2', 'GPR172A', 'RTN4', 'GAPDH', 'MAPK13', 'FKBP8', 'PTGER3', 'BSCL2', 'TUBG1', 'FAM162A', 'GDI1', 'SPTLC2', 'YWHAZ', 'BCAP31', 'OSBPL1A', 'ATP6AP1', 'CALM1', 'PEX16', 'MYCBP2']

ARNTL = ['NCAM1', 'SLC11A2', 'RPL35A', 'PDLIM5', 'RPL31', 'NFIB', 'GYG2', 'IGHG1', 'NAAA', 'DLC1', 'EPOR', 'DIO2', 'ESR1', 'KLK10', 'CYP2C9', 'SPN', 'RPS9', 'PRELP', 'CYP3A43', 'PLAGL1', 'COBLL1']
```

I have a function to compare these lists with one reference list, which produces the number of matching between ref and each of the remaining lists.

```
def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)
    for matches, name, a_list in lists:
        print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))
```

Every time, I change the `ref`, I have to copy paste the below long code.

```
sort_by_matches(APP, [("ABCC8", ABCC8), ("APP", APP), ("BECN1", BECN1), ("ARNTL", ARNTL), ("BMI1", BMI1), ("CASP8", CASP8), ("CASP9", CASP9), ("CLOCK", CLOCK), ("CRAT", CRAT), ("CRY2", CRY2), ("CSF1", CSF1), ("CTCF", CTCF), ("DNMT1", DNMT1), ("EP300", EP300), ("FBXW7", FBXW7), ("FOXA1", FOXA1), ("FOXO1", FOXO1), ("FOXO3", FOXO3), ("GADD", GADD), ("GAT", GAT), ("GCK", GCK), ("GLI1", GLI1), ("GLP1", GLP1), ("GLP1R", GLP1R), ("GLUT1", GLUT1),("GLUT2", GLUT2),("HES1", HES1),("HEY1", HEY1),("HIF1A", HIF1A),("HNF", HNF),("HNF33", HNF33),("ICM33", ICM33),("ID11", ID11),("IDHA11", IDHA11),("IL44", IL44),("IL65", IL56),("LC44", LC44),("LYL2", LYL2),("MFSD", MFSD)])
```

How can I call the function in a very short form?

Comment: Can't you just keep the list of tuple as a variable and then call `sort_by_matches(APP, list_of_tuples)` ?

Comment: @Mel, tried that, works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_of_tuples = ([("ABCC8", ABCC8), ("APP", APP), ("BECN1", BECN1), ("ARNTL", ARNTL), ("BMI1", BMI1), ("CASP8", CASP8), ("CASP9", CASP9), ("CLOCK", CLOCK), ("CRAT", CRAT), ("CRY2", CRY2), ("CSF1", CSF1), ("CTCF", CTCF), ("DNMT1", DNMT1), ("EP300", EP300), ("FBXW7", FBXW7), ("FOXA1", FOXA1), ("FOXO1", FOXO1), ("FOXO3", FOXO3), ("GADD", GADD), ("GAT", GAT), ("GCK", GCK), ("GLI1", GLI1), ("GLP1", GLP1), ("GLP1R", GLP1R), ("GLUT1", GLUT1),("GLUT2", GLUT2),("HES1", HES1),("HEY1", HEY1),("HIF1A", HIF1A),("HNF", HNF),("HNF33", HNF33),("ICM33", ICM33),("ID11", ID11),("IDHA11", IDHA11),("IL44", IL44),("IL65", IL56),("LC44", LC44),("LYL2", LYL2),("MFSD", MFSD)])

sort_by_matches(APP, list_of_tuples)
```